# Server-less search engine using Firebase and Lunr.js or other helping libraries

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, polymer, full-text-indexing, lunrjs

Firebase does not really have the capabilities in full-text searching yet so I was wondering if Lunr.js can help (or other libraries). I'd like to know how or to create a good scheme in indexing data directly in Firebase and if Lunr.js can help me with this? I'd like to implement searching without downloading a lot of data from Firebase, just parts of indexed information. Any suggested schemes or libraries to process the indexes?

PS. No server-codes please. I can't afford another tier :D Thanks!